# Enforce references to only fields that exist for an inline object definition?

Tags: typescript

I want to quickly declare an object where the fields are enforced to be of a specific type (`CSSProperties` in this example, but I want a generic type in the end).

When I use an indexed type (or `Record`), TS restricts values of the member field values to the correct type and will throw errors if I mis-define their contents.  But it loses knowledge about what fields have been defined, so a reference to an undefined field will not give a compile error and the caller just gets `undefined`.

```ts
export const simpleStyle = {
  a: {
    margin: 0,
  },
  b: {
    margin: 0,
    wibble: 'blah', // no compile error: BAD
  },
} 

const simpleA = simpleStyle.a;
// causes a compile error: GOOD
// const simpleB = simpleStyle.wibble;

export type CssStyles = { [index: string]: CSSProperties };

export const typedStyle: CssStyles = {
  a: {
    margin: 0,
  },
  b: {
    margin: 0,
    // causes a compile error : GOOD
    // wibble: 'blah',
  },
}

const typedA = typedStyle.a;
// does not cause a compile error
const typedB = typedStyle.wibble;
```

How do I define this type such that Typescript considers references to undefined indexes as invalid?  Where "defined" is determined by the contents of the object I declare (I don't want to have to redefine all the fields in a union and I don't want to define an explicit type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce and type and at the same infer a more specific subtype, then you have to use a generic function.

```
function createStyles<K extends string>(
  styles: Record<K, CSSProperties>
): Record<K, CSSProperties> {
  return styles
}
```

In your case you want to infer the keys of the object, but you want to the values to be a strict known type. That means you capture the keys as `K`, and use that as the keys for the object the function accepts.

This also uses [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to pair keys with values in an object.

Now this works as you expect:

```
export const typedStyle = createStyles({
  a: {
    margin: 0,
  },
  b: {
    margin: 0,
    wibble: 'blah', // error
  },
})

const typedA = typedStyle.a;
const typedB = typedStyle.wibble; // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgynACgJwPaWcAlhAzlAXigG8oBbAQ2QHMsA7ALijoFcyAjCZKAXwCg+EAB5hUmKKEixcuOKAA2eADwAVAHyESUANqIo9KAGsIIVADMoKgLpN4SNBmx5eAbgFmWdAMbZUdKF7IEBTAEHIgirhKANJQwqF0ACb4uMDI9NRqABR8UFCpEXhMAEoQXmKJMQA0sAgo6FxOuGp8AJQlZRXVtfYNmDjNJLlQQcAsyP4FkXz8giJiwAF+qRLgEInhipqBwaGbeFnEwxRMR3l5lDT0TAAMVcM893nsp8MXVLSMUHdvUADuWHY7EUTAA5MCKAALUE1AD0sLiyDQyAe9x4rQE5ToK0k6wAgppcRsFBAAHQUNxYnFrRIAIUJNP2pIBQMULig8MRyL4QA)

---

Lastly, I'll add that the Typescript team is working an upcoming feature to make the function not required via [the `satisfies` operator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920).

Comment: Thanks!  I seem to have  blind spot for these "type forcing" functions.  Is there a name for the technique?  Does TS know that this function exists just to communicate with the compiler? (So it could, after type checking succeeds, just tree-shake the method call since it does nothing?)

Comment: It's just a generic function, nothing special about it really. It exists at runtime and does pretty much nothing at runtime. But the typescript team is working on improving this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920